# Redirecting stdout and stderr to a file in c++

Tags: c++, linux, logging, stdout

I am trying to redirect stdout and stderr to a log file.

```
/* Redirecting stderr buffer to stdout */
dup2(fileno(stdout), fileno(stderr));

/* Redirecting stdout buffer to logfile */
    if((LogStream = freopen(LogPath.c_str(), "w", stdout)) == NULL)
    {
            cout << "Failed to redirect console logs\n";
    }   

.
.
. //other code
.
.
fclose(LogStream);
LogStream = freopen (NULL_LOG, "w", stdout);
```

This is what i am doing. But still i am missing out some of the logs. I came to know that when i executed my application commenting out these lines of code. I am dubious about this code snippet. Please provide your feedback on this.

Comment: I think that you should provide more context. What are the messages that are not in the log? When and where on the code they were triggered? These aspects should answer your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first close stdout and stderr

```
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDERR_FILENO)
```

open new file to write logs to.

```
int file = open( "logfile", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644 );
```

duplicate the logfile file descriptor to use with stdout and stderr. see `man dup2`

```
dup2( file, STDOUT_FILENO);
dup2( file, STDERR_FILENO);
```

I hope above code help you..

Comment: Flag is "O_CREAT" and not "O_CREATE"

Comment: It's a typo. My bad. Thank you for pointing it. I corrected it.